# Android NDK and shared library (libskia_android.so)

Tags: android-ndk

When I call a methods that are declared and defined in the header file I get SIGSEGV!
When I call a methods that are not defined in header (they are implemented in .cpp file) everything works fine.

How linker works?How to solve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Which method caused SIGSEGV? Could you provide the name, please?

Comment: class "SkPath"; method "const SkRect& getBounds() const"; This is definition in SkPath.h const SkRect& getBounds() const {
        return fPathRef->getBounds();
    } .If i put defintion in SkPath.cpp and recompile libskia_android.so everything works fine!

Comment: I googled for the function and have found a bit different definition. Are you sure you use the header and the binary for the same revision?

Comment: That was my first thought, but yes, I am 100% sure.

Comment: It's a bit unclear: when you call a) _methods other than getBounds()_ **OR** b) _getBounds() whose definition is moved to the .cpp file_ everything works fine?

Comment: Yes that is same true for other methods. When I move them to .cpp works fine.

Comment: **1)** You call `SkPath::getBounds()` from where? **2)** Do you replace `/system/lib/libskia_android.so`, or put the rebuilt library elsewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I figure out what is problem!
In Android.mk must be included "LOCAL_CFLAGS += -DSKIA_DLL".
This will prevent instance counting. Instance counting relies on static
variables in functions defined in header files,which increase size of class and changes the application binary interface (ABI) !